# Email Notifications Chrome Webstore Support

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is it possible to receive email notification for new comments on the Support page of a Chrome extension in the webstore?

On the support page of a Chrome extension I can add a new question, suggestion or bug report but I don't receive any notification about responses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have several apps in the Chrome Web Store and I found it tedious to be constantly checking. I found an extension that claimed to have this functionality, though I found it periodically lost my list of extensions and wasn't able to actually fetch reviews consistently. You can try the extension here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-extensions/igejgfmbjjjjplnnlgnbejpkpdajkblm?hl=en. It is also open source, so it could be improved.

I ended up writing some of my own scripts to periodically check and send me an email when there is a new review or support request. I made it available to use as a hosted service (currently free, though I plan on asking for a little money to defray the hosting costs as well as some coffee money). Check out the hosted service at https://www.chromebeat.com. It has a full list of the Chrome webstore apps and extensions and can send you notifications on a new support issue or review. Right now it only checks hourly and sends on the hour.

Also, when you respond to a support request, the user who reported it doesn't get any kind of notification. The best way around that I've found is to actually message that person's Google+ profile, either by adding them to a circle (e.g. App users) posting publicly and mentioning them in the post, or for some users it's possible to message directly with hangouts.

[update: Oct 2015. It's now possible to "Reply" to reviews in the web store, so that's probably the best way to respond to user reviews directly]

Comment: I'm quite torn on this. On one hand, you're effectively promoting your own paid service and therefore this should be torched as spam. On the other, your advice is solid. You can redeem this answer by actually adding a script that can do this here, and saying that "I'm also offering a hosted service that will do it for you".

Comment: Thanks! The answer is now much improved.

Comment: Chromebeat is no longer free.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no such option. You will have to periodically check it.

Which makes using the built-in Feedback quite useless - you're better off using something like a public bug tracker as your "Support" link and disabling Feedback.

Existing feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=295837
As of 2015-03-23, it is untriaged.

Comment: This is not understandable. What is the best way to contact the Webstore team to please implement this feature?

Comment: Existing untriaged feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=295837 You could try raising this (i.e. asking for triage of the bug) on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions) (but it's considered deprecated) or the [Developer Support](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/) channel

Comment: Yes. Extremely lame. Has been lame for years. Doesnt even include the user email.

Answer (score 0):

No, that has not been implemented, even approaching a decade later.

**New Solution:**

The two options in the current answer are no longer working, so I made a small utility app to solve this problem.

You can submit your extension's id and your email address and Webstore Watch will notify you within 1 minute of a new support request.

https://gmanicus.github.io/WebstoreWatch/

Let me know if this goes down or if you experience problems. I can't guarantee 100% reliability, but I will do my best to maintain it.